# .Where with LINQ on custom collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I'm trying to return a collection of items, from an existing `ConcurrentHashSet` but only selecting the ones by a certain `ID`, I've coded the LINQ for it, the only thing I'm struggling with is it returns a `IEnumerable` and I have a custom `ConcurrentHashSet` class and I'm unsure how to convert it?

I've tried casting it using `(ConcurrentHashSet)` but it hasn't worked, my `ConcurrentHashSet` does implement `IEnumerable` so I'm guessing it is possible..

```
public ConcurrentHashSet<Item> GetItemsById(int id)
{
    return Items.Where(x => x.HasLoaded && x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your ConcurrentHashSet that returns the IEnumerable? What is the type of "Items"?

Comment: Why do you need to "convert" it? Why operation do you need to do that `IEnumerable<>` doesn't provide?

Comment: The title states exactly that, its a custom type but inherits IEnumerable. I need to convert it because the return type on .Where is enumerable and it has to be ConcurrentHashSet.

Comment: I would suggest checking the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606488/using-concurrenthashset-in-foreach . _You should use `ConcurrentDictionary` as suggested there._

Answer (score 1):

`.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and you cannot change that. Explicit casting as you tried does not work because through every `ConcurrentHashSet` is an `IEnumerable` (inherits), an `IEnumerable` is not necessarily a `ConcurrentHashSet`. The compiler can't say.

- Either instantiate a new `ConcurrentHashSet` (assuming it has a
  constructor receiving an `IEnumerable`, which it should have):

  ```
  return new ConcurrentHashSet<Item>(Items.Where(x => x.HasLoaded && x.Id == id));
  ```
- Or change your method to return `IEnumerable<Item>`

Answer (score -1):

Code below returns a collection since it is enumerable in a foreach :

```
   public class Test
    {
        ConcurrentHashSet hashSet = new ConcurrentHashSet();
        public Test() 
        {
            foreach (ConcurrentHashSet set in hashSet.GetItemsById(123))
            {
            }
        }


    }

    public class ConcurrentHashSet : HashSet<ConcurrentHashSet>
    {
        public Boolean HasLoaded { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<ConcurrentHashSet> GetItemsById(int id)
        {
            return this.Where(x =>  x.HasLoaded && x.Id == id).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The request is to manage to return an `ConcurrentHashSet<Item>` and not a collection of `ConcurrentHashSet<Item>`.  `ConcurrentHashSet<Item>` is already a collection

Comment: The asker wants a `ConcurrentHashSet<Item>` to be returned. This code returns `List<ConcurrentHashSet>`.

Comment: The OP didn't define an interface Item and it may not be needed.